# Create a Copy of Sheets from existing (unknown named) workbook into a new (unknown named) workbook

Tags: vba, excel, google-sheets

I have an existing workbook that will be used by multiple users (who will name the workbook uniquely - I can set one Workbook Codename if needed though, though don't know how to do this?).

I need to create a macro that opens a new workbook (which presumably I won't know the name of? as it could be 'Book1', 'Book2', 'Book3' etc?), then returns to the original workbook where the macro is stored, and copies several (can do one at a time if needed) sheets (that I DO know the names of these sheets) and pastes them as new sheets into the new workbook that I created at the start. The macro does not need to Save the file (in fact it's preferable that it doesn't as I want the user to save the new workbook wherever is most convenient for the user).

I have attempted to show what the macro would do, showing the obvious problem that I do not know the names of the workbooks I am creating/copying from/pasting into.

Any help, much appreciated!

```
Sub CopySheetintoNewWorkbook()

'Macro opens new / blank workbook (name unknown?)'
    Workbooks.Add

'Macro goes back to original workbook where macro is saved (of which the name is unknown to the macro - i.e., users can and will change it)'
    Windows("UnknownWorkbookName-1").Activate

'Macro goes to a sheet which can be named and will be known, so this is no problem'
    Sheets("KnownSheet").Select
'Macro creates a copy of the sheet and pastes it as a new sheet within the new, unknown named workbook'
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("KnownSheet").Copy Before:=Workbooks("UnknownWorkbookName-2").Sheets(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use thisworkbook.name to get the name of the workbook you are running the macro from and use that to reference later. similarly you can force assign a name after workbook.add

Comment: Right after `Workbooks.Add`, do something like `Dim newWB as Workbook`, then `Set newWB = ThisWorkbook`.  Then you can use `newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").Value` or whatever.  *Or*, `Dim newWB as String`, `newWB = Thisworkbook.name`, then you would refer to it like `Workbooks(newWB).Sheets("Sheet1")...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to copy *Sheet1* and *Sheet2*.

This relies on a tiny trick:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wbNEW As Workbook
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
    Set wbNEW = ActiveWorkbook
    wb1.Sheets("Sheet2").Copy after:=wbNEW.Sheets(1)
End Sub
```

When the first *.Copy* is performed, a new workbook is created and it becomes the *ActiveWorkbook* ........the rest is easy.

**EDIT#1:**

If we have a group of sheets to be copied, then we can create an array of sheet names and loop through the array, copying  one sheet at a time:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wbNEW As Workbook
    Dim ary() As String, s As String, i As Long

    s = "Larry,Moe,Curly"
    ary = Split(s, ",")
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    i = 1

    For Each a In ary
        If i = 1 Then
            Sheets(a).Copy
            Set wbNEW = ActiveWorkbook
        Else
            wb1.Sheets(a).Copy after:=wbNEW.Sheets(1)
        End If
        i = 2
    Next a

    wbNEW.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Any difference in using `Activeworkbook` instead of `Thisworkbook`? (I'm still trying to learn when to use which)

Comment: @BruceWayne  Using *ThisWorkbook* restricts you to have the sheets in the same workbook as the code...........but this is probably O.K. in most cases.

Comment: So, if your code is in Workbook1, when you `.Copy` the workbook and use `ThisWorkbook`, then `ThisWorkbook` would refer back to Workbook1, not the new one?  So, using `Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook` would just be like doing `Set wb1 = Workbook("Workbook1")` so to speak?

Comment: @BruceWayne ...Here is the only case where it makes a difference.  Say we started with **two** workbooks, *MacroMaster.xlsm* containing the macros and data.xlsx containing *Sheet1* and Sheet2*.  If we use `ThisWorkbook`, we would be trying to copy sheets from the `.xlsm` rather than the `.xlsx`.

Comment: I'll be honest... I'm not really sure how it does it, but it works a dream! Thank you @Gary'sStudent! - quick quesiton. If I want to switch back to the original workbook and delete Sheet1 and Sheet2 (as the first part of the bigger macro will create Sheet1 and Sheet2, so I need them deleted once put into a new workbook), how can I go back to the original workbook so I can continue the rest of the macro there?

Comment: Alsoo.... let's assume I have more than 2 sheets. Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4, etc etc. How do I move those over? Also.. if I want to go back into the new workbook and do something like hide one of the sheets (say Sheet4), how do I do that?

Comment: Nevermind..! I figured it out. Just  --   wb1.Sheets("Sheet3").Copy after:=wbNEW.Sheets(1)  -- after! And then to move back to the other workbooks, just wb1.Activate or wbNEW.Activate. Thanks @Gary'sStudent!

Comment: @cosmo  See my **EDIT#1**